# How to connect angular front end with remote mysql server with php api?

Tags: mysql, angular

[image: login page image]

I have angular front end login page in my local system.I have to authenticate users login.Users data resides in remote server. Using PHP api i need to connect with mysql database in remote server for authentication.So what is the front end code to connect with it?

**login.component.html**

```html
<h1 class="text-center">Login Form</h1>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-18 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-3 col- 
md-0ffset-4">
                <form #f="ngForm" name="theForm">
                    <div id="user-data">
                      <div class="form-group">

                          <label for="username">UserName</label>
                          <input type="text" id="username"
                          class="form-control"
                          ngModel name="username"
                          required
                          #username="ngModel"
                         >
                          <span class="help-block" *ngIf="!username.valid 
&& username.touched">Enter UserName !</span>
                          <label for="password">Password</label>
                          <input type="password" id="password"
                          class="form-control"
                          ngModel name="password"
                          required
                          #password="ngModel"
                         >
                         <span class="help-block" *ngIf="!password.valid 
&& password.touched">Enter Password !</span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="btn-toolbar">
                          <button class="btn btn-primary " type="submit" 
[disabled]="!f.valid">Login</button>
                          <button class="btn btn-primary" 
type="button">Cancel</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
              </div>
          </div>
</div>
```

**login.component.ts**

```typescript
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
selector: 'app-login',
templateUrl: './login.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor() { }

 ngOnInit() {
 }
 }
```

Comment: what i should include in type script to connect with remote server.

Comment: from what I understand, you have to send HTTP request to the server side, that contains user login and password

Comment: if it's rest api then using HttpClient you can do that

Comment: Lunin Roman how can i send http request to remote server and verify the user. send any example code snippet or reference link?

Answer (score 0):

I am using something like the following:

At the angular side, I created an api containing all methods related to server side, like login, logout, adding, editing...

When the login button is clicked, run the following:

```
login() {
    //Delete current JWT token if already exists
    localStorage.removeItem('jwt');
    this.auth.loggedIn = false;
    this.showMsg=false;
    //Get username and password
    const user = this.loginGroup.get('username').value;
    const pass = this.loginGroup.get('password').value;

    this.auth.login(user, pass).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        if (data['user_exist'] == 'true') {
          this.showMsg = false;
          //Save the JWT in local storage
          localStorage.setItem('jwt', data['jwt']);
          localStorage.setItem('user_id', data['user_id']);


          //console.log('login component ' + data);
          this.auth.loggedIn = true;

          this.globalVar.user_logged = true;
          this.globalVar.username = data['username'];
          this.globalVar.jwt_token = data['jwt'];
          this.globalVar.user_role = data['user_role'];
          this.globalVar.user_id = data['user_id'];
          this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
        }
        else {
          this.showMsg = true;
          this.msgTxt = data['errorMsg'];
          if(this.msgTxt=="Incorrect Password!!!")
          {
            this.loginGroup.controls['password'].reset();

            }
            this.globalVar.user_recovery='';
            //console.log(failedAttempt);
          }


          this.auth.loggedIn = false;
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error.message)
        if(error.message=="Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error")
        {
          //this.showMsg=true;
          this.msgTxt = "Connection Error. Please try again, when a connection exists";
          this.showMsg=true;
        }
      }
    )
  }
```

This line:

```
this.auth.login(user, pass).subscribe()
```

Will go to api service created in angular, to run the desired method and subscribe to response from the server:

```
login(username, password): Observable<any> {
    let headerOptions = new HttpHeaders();
    headerOptions.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    headerOptions.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headerOptions.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');


    this.credentials = { user: username, pass: password };
    const httpParams = new HttpParams()
      .set('username', username)
      .set('password', password);


    return this.http.post(this.globalVar.login, httpParams, {
      headers: headerOptions,
    })
  }
```

You can get the variables in your PHP scripts, as `$_POST['username']` and `$_POST['password']`.

The following line:

```
this.globalVar.login
```

is the url of the login code, on virtual host that I've created on wamp server, and it looks like that:

```
login = 'http://dev.local/scripts/login.php';
```

At the php side, the script is easy. Just check if the user exists, and use `password_hash()` (P.S. Read more about how to use this method) to check if the password is the right one if the user exists, and return whatever you want(array, boolean, text,...) using `json_encode($result)`.

It is important to create virtual hosts, when working with PHP and angular for the reasons mentioned in this [article](https://john-dugan.com/wamp-vhost-setup/). The same article, contain steps on how to create the vhost.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on the same platform (PHP+MySQL & PHP+Mongo).

Create POST service and pass two parameters here I am considering email and password from the front end.

1. **HTML**

```html
<input type="email" [(ngModel)]="email">
<input type="password" [(ngModel)]="password">
<button (click)="login()">Login</button>
```

i.e.

1. **In login.component.ts** :

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginService } from '../login.service';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import * as alertify from 'alertify.js'; // for alerts
import { LocalStorage } from '@ngx-pwa/local-storage'; //for localstorage
import {Router} from "@angular/router"; //to route after successfull login

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  auth : Object; //to store response from api
  email : string; //front end variable
  password : string; //front end variable
  


  constructor(private data : LoginService,protected localStorage: LocalStorage,private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  login(){

    //console.log(this.email,this.password);

    if(this.email == null && this.email == undefined && this.email == '' && this.password == null && this.password == undefined && this.password == ''){
      alertify.error('Please enter username and password');
    }
    else
      if(this.email == null || this.email == undefined || this.email == '' || this.password == null || this.password == undefined || this.password == ''){
        alertify.error('Please fill all the fields');
    }
    else
      if(this.email != null || this.email != undefined || this.email != '' || this.password != null || this.password != undefined || this.password != ''){
      this.data.loginService({
        "email":this.email,
        "password":this.password
      }).subscribe(data => {

        let auth = data ;

        if(data == 'false'){
          alertify.error("Invalid Password");  
          //false => response from php api
        }
        else
          if(data == 'user_does_not_exist'){
          //user_does_not_exist => response from php api
          alertify.error("User does not exist");   
        }
        else
          if(data == 'error_fetching_email' || data == 'error_fetching_user'){
          //error_fetching_email , error_fetching_user => response from php api
          alertify.log("Database error !! Please try again later");   
        }
        else
        if(data != '[]' && data != '' && data != undefined && data != null && data != 'false'){
        //if data return value
          this.localStorage.setItem('user', btoa(JSON.stringify(auth[0]))).subscribe(() => {
            alertify.success("Login Successfull !!"); 

  //JSON.stringify convert Object to string then btoa() method of angular to encrypt given string

            this.router.navigate(['/main_nav']);
             
          }, () => {
            alertify.error("Storage error"); 
          });
        }
        else{
          alertify.error("Something went wrong !! Please try again later");        
        } 
      });
    }  
    else{
      alertify.error('Somethings wrong !! Please contact Support Staffs');
    }
    
  }

}
```

2. **Service** :

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs'; //observables to catch errors
import { retry, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators'; //for handling errors generated by code

import * as alertify from 'alertify.js'; //alert messages check alertyfy.js

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService {

  constructor(private Http : HttpClient) { }

    loginService(data) {
      return this.Http.post('http://localhost:8080/auth/login',data)
      .pipe(
          retry(1),
          catchError(this.handleError) //will call handleError
        );
     }

      handleError(error) {
        let errorMessage = '';
        if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
          // client-side error
          // errorMessage = `${error.error.text}`;
          alertify.error("Connection Problem !! Please try again"); 
        }
        else{
         alertify.error("Something went wrong !! Please try again later");   
        }
        return throwError(errorMessage);
    }

}
```

Happy coding **:v**